# Copy properties using .map() typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to copy selected properties from one `object` to another based on a condition(`key`).

**//Code**

```
var abc = [{"name":"John", "age":30, "state":"WS", "id": 1}, {"name":"Wille", "age":36, "state":"SFO", "id": 2}, {"name":"Rack", "age":18, "state":"NJ", "id": 3}]

var xyz = [{"weight":69, "height":180, "mobile":4457158, "id": 1}, {"weight":77, "height":178, "mobile":5896854, "id": 2}, {"weight":56, "height":140, "mobile":568574, "id": 3}]
```

I wanted to copy only the properties (`height`, `mobile`) from `xyz` to `abc`.

I tried,

```
const result = abc.map(x=> ({...x, ...xyz.find(y=> y.id === x.id)}));
```

Even in the above i couldn't copy the entire properties. What went wrong and how can i copy the selected one?

Comment: "Copy the entire properties." What do you mean by that? In your code it doesn't look like you're trying to copy a specific item from the first object?

Comment: What i see is that you are trying to copy whole object, can you state your problem correctly.

Comment: @code Yeah i first tried to copy all with which i could try to filter to selected but even that didn't work. My ultimate goal is to copy selected.

Comment: try const result = abc.map(x =>{
    
    let y=xyz.find(y => y.id === x.id)
    if(y){
        let {weight,height}=y;
        
        return {...x,weight,height}
    }
    
    return {...x}
    
})

Comment: @JohnLobo Is there something missing before the if?

Comment: @ACoder no. i dont think so

Comment: @JohnLobo There was a compiler error, may be a comma is expected before or after if

Comment: try adding comma ,const result = abc.map(x =>{
    
    let y=xyz.find(y => y.id === x.id);
    if(y){
        let {weight,height}=y;
        
        return {...x,weight,height};
    }
    
    return {...x};
    
})  and also format code while pasting

Comment: Typescript without Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just do this in steps:

```
const result = abc.map((x) => {
  const { height, mobile } = xyz.find((y) => y.id === x.id) || {};
  return { ...x, height, mobile };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear understanding and the solution rather than just asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in js, but in typescript, find could return undefined which means the resulting array will have possibly undefined properties.

```
interface Person = {
  id: number;
  state: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

interface Stats = {
  id: number;
  weight: number;
  height: number;
  mobile: number;
};

interface Merged extends Person, Stats {}
```

Consider using `find() as Stats` if you know the arrays contain the data or wish to ignore that the id may not be found.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner and for the sake of the parentheses, you can create an IIFE wrapping the object:

```js
abc.map(x => ({ ...x, ...(({ mobile, height }) => ({ mobile, height }))(xyz.find(y => x.id === y.id)) }));
```

Basically we spread `x`, which you're already doing, then spread an IIFE with destructured parameters to return only the data we want, passing our `find()` results as the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var abc = [{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "state": "WS",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "name": "Wille",
  "age": 36,
  "state": "SFO",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "name": "Rack",
  "age": 18,
  "state": "NJ",
  "id": 3
}];

var xyz = [{
  "weight": 69,
  "height": 180,
  "mobile": 4457158,
  "id": 1
}, {
  "weight": 77,
  "height": 178,
  "mobile": 5896854,
  "id": 2
}, {
  "weight": 56,
  "height": 140,
  "mobile": 568574,
  "id": 3
}];

function copy(from, to, keys) {
  const mapped = from.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return { ...acc,
      [el.id]: el
    }
  }, {});

  return to.map(el => {
    const extracted = keys.reduce((acc, k) => ({ ...acc,
      [k]: mapped[el.id][k]
    }), {});
    return { ...el,
      ...extracted
    };
  });
}

console.log(copy(xyz, abc, ['height', 'weight']));
```